# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL - Dockerized PHP Project Cannot Load WSDL from External URL

Tags: php, docker-compose, soap, proxy

I'm encountering a

> "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL"

issue while working on my Dockerized PHP project. The project involves consuming a SOAP web service, and I'm getting the error "Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://myprivateurl/ressources/services/service?wsdl' : failed to load external entity." Here's a clear explanation of my setup and the problem I'm facing:

Project Overview:

- I'm working on a Dockerized PHP project running on a WSL Linux
  distribution. The host machine is Windows 10.  I have a proxy server
  with the following details:
- Proxy  Hostname:private_proxy
- Proxy Port: 8000
- Proxy Username:private
- Proxy Password: private

I've configured the proxysettings in both my Docker Compose file and the PHP code. The Issue:

My PHP code uses a custom SOAP client (soapClientSecure) to interact with the SOAP service.
When I try to create the SOAP client instance and load the WSDL from the URL http://myprivateurl/ressources/services/service?wsdl', I get the "Parsing WSDL" error mentioned above.

I've double-checked the URL, proxy settings, and network connectivity, but I'm still unable to load the WSDL.
What I've Tried:

I've added proxy settings to both my Docker Compose environment and PHP code using the proxy host, port, username, and password.

```
  groomrhv2-php:
build:
  context: './.docker/php'
depends_on:
  - postgresql
image: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php
container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php
volumes:
  - "./:/var/www/html:cached"
  - "./.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini"
  - "./.docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini"
  - "./.docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini"
  - "./.docker/php/xdebug.log:/tmp/xdebug.log"
privileged: true
environment:
  - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=groomrhv2-php
  - http_proxy=http://private_proxy:8000
  - https_proxy=http://private_proxy:8000
  - HTTP_PROXY_AUTH=private:private
  - no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

I've ensured that DNS resolution is working within the Docker container and that network connectivity is established.

I've tried accessing the WSDL URL directly from within the container using tools like curl and verified that it's accessible.

I've disabled WSDL caching using ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);.

I've implemented error handling in my code to catch and display SOAP faults.

I tried to make a curl inside the container :

```
docker exec -ti php_container bash

curl http://myprivateurl/ressources/services/service?wsdl
```

I'm getting

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host

this is the php code where i'm trying to create a new soap client that call the private url :

```
    private function construitClientSoap(string $sWsdl, SaeContratService $contratService)
{
    $classmap = array(
        'rechercheResponseType' => rechercheResponse::class,
        'rechercheNbResResponseType' => rechercheNbResResponse::class,
        'listeResultatRechercheType' => resultats::class,
        'listeResultatRechercheNbResType' => resultats::class,
        'resultatRechercheType' => resultatRecherche::class,
        'metadonneeType' => metadonnee::class,
        'listeMetadonneeType' => metadonnees::class,
        'recuperationMetadonneesResponseType' => recuperationMetadonneesResponse::class,
        'listeMetadonneeDispoType' => listeMetadonneeDispo::class,
        'metadonneeDispoType' => metadonneeDispo::class,
    );
    $sLocation = substr(trim($sWsdl), 0, -5);

    $proxyHost = '****';
    $proxyPort = **;
    $proxyUsername = '****';
    $proxyPassword = '******!';

    $options = [
        //'location' => $sLocation,
        'trace' => 1,
        //'classmap' => $classmap,
        //'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'proxy_host' => $proxyHost,
        'proxy_port' => $proxyPort,
        'proxy_login' => $proxyUsername,
        'proxy_password' => $proxyPassword,
    ];
    $client = new soapClientSecure($sWsdl, $options);
    $client->setWssedoc($this->getWsseSecurityDocument($contratService));
    return $client;
}
```

I'm getting :

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '***privateurl?wsdl' :
> failed to load external entity "***privateurl?wsdl?wsdl" in
> /var/www/html/***/i***GED/gedClient.php:l.99

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to resolve the "Parsing WSDL" error.
I'm looking for guidance on how to properly configure my Dockerized environment to consume the SOAP API and load the WSDL successfully.
Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve non-public domains, you need to add `extra_hosts` to `docker-compose.yml`.

```
extra_hosts:
    "yourprivatehost:ip12.address34.of56.host78"
```

See

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host

Comment: thank you for your help, what is this syntax ? ip12.address34.of56.host78  it's a standard IP address N

Comment: It's not a syntax, just put the IP you want to associate with the hostname like `"myprivateurl:192.168.2.100"`.

Comment: i added the IP address i still can't use the private host

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara after restarting the container, it should have appropriate host mapping in `/etc/hosts`, what's in yours?

Comment: note that i'm working under wsl2 with docker , i started the container, inside hosts file i have myprivateurl:IP  configured

Comment: If you have the IP in the hosts file, it worked. You can now resolve the host. You must have a new, different error message now.

Comment: i have always this error : SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from url

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara in your profile you write "highly skilled developer" - please bring some basic debug information, I cannot guess where your configuration went wrong.

Comment: i updated my question, i can't call the Web Service  when i'm using docker under wsl 2 and a proxy,  the web service is protecte by a proxy and a vpn  and i don't find a way to handle docker network to be able to fetch the web service,

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara try again with `curl` - what is the output of the curl command now that you are manually resolving your privatehost ?

Comment: with curl i'm getting :  cURL Error: Could not resolve proxy

Comment: i set the proxy correctly to docker and now i'm getting Could not resolve host: my_private_host,   the private host is the web service called with curl

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara put the IP address and FQDN of `my_private_host` in the `/etc/hosts` file in the container (via the options in my answer) and the resolve will succeed.

Comment: i don't really understand, i have an IP address for my_private_host  i puted inside /etc/hosts of the wsl ,  should i add the proxy FQDN... ?

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara you need to add all hosts that you cannot resolve via public DNS. You can try the most simple way in the container run `host my_private_host` - if it returns the IP address, resolving works. If not, you put something wrong in `/etc/hosts`.